# Q.1.6.1 in Guillemin and pollack.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The question and its answer is given below:

[image]

But I do not understand why in the second line of the solution $\widetilde{F}$ is defined as this, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $\widetilde F$ is this way so that it has the desired properties, namely $\widetilde F(x,t)=f_0(x)$ for $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $\widetilde F(x,t)=f_1(x)$ for $\frac34\leq t\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need it to do the right thing and you need the co/domains to match up the right way. It may be better to think of $h$ as a map $h: I \to I$.  Then $\mathrm{Id} \times h: X \times I \to X \times I$ via $(x,t) \mapsto (x, h(t))$.  Now compose with $F$ to get $F \circ (\mathrm{Id} \times h) : X \times I \to Y$ which has all the properties that you want (check it).  Hence take this to be $\widetilde{F}$ and be done.

Comment: But actually the map $h$ is not from $I$ to $I$ .... How can I think of it like that?

Comment: Sure it is.  Or, it can be.  Its image is within $I$, and you can restrict its domain to $I$.  (We don't actually know what Exercise 1.1.18 is on this site.)

Comment: I will add it in the question ..... by the way the way thank you so much for your response for my trivial  question .... I appreciate this :) too much.